# Meaning of `@` in `&isprint`

Tags: default-settings

As far as I'm concerned "printable characters" are the set of characters that occupies a printing position on a display. You can print a subset of (not all) printable characters by executing `:echo &isprint`.

```
:echo &isprint
@,161-255
```

The speciications present in `vim` documentation are concise. According to `:h 'isprint'`, characters from space (decimal value: 32) to tilde (decimal value: 126) are considered as printable characters, even they are not included in `'isprint'` or excluded. This raises the following question: why is the at sign (`@`) explicitly specified within the set of characters that is displayed by executing `:h 'isprint'` while the other characters are represented by a range of decimal values. Does this implies something significant? Is the at sign considered as something more than a simple character?

Comment: as you say the specifications are concise: as documented at `:help isfname`, `@` stands for all "alphabetic characters," the meaning of which is locale-dependent.